# Address function returns two ":" for single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble understanding some strange behavior. The .address property of the range class is returning a cell in "Cell:Cell" format. Both (1) and (2) give the address in the form of "$A$1:$A$1" instead of simply "$A$1". A snippet of code is listed below:

```
With Sheet1
        Set r = .Range("MyRange")

        '(1)*
        Debug.Print r.Address 
        r.Formula = "= 1 + 1"

        For i = 1 To 47
            Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)

            'above
            r1 = r.Offset(-1, 0).Address(True, False)

            'above to the left
            r2 = r.Offset(-1, -1).Address(True, False)

            'to the left
            r3 = r.Offset(0, -1).Address(False, False)
            '(2)*
            Debug.Print r.Address & "gets: " & r1 & "+" & r2 & "+" r3
        Next
End With
```

Debug.Print in either case prints in the format:

```
"$D$10:$D$10 gets: $D$9:$D$9 + $C$8:$C$8 + ... " and so on.
```

*Note: 
I'm not saying that (1) and (2) print the same thing.. they both print as expected, it's just the format of what is printed is repeated twice as a range of one cell.*

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated - B

**EDIT:** When I save and close out of the workbook, the behavior stops and it returns to printing addresses as expected "$D$10 gets: ... "

Comment: Excel version and OS?  I don't see this behavior (Win7/Excel 2010)  How is the named range defined?

Comment: agree with @TimWilliams. Unable to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7. Named range is defined as an ordinary single cell through the native Excel UI. Nothing special there. After saving, closing and reopening, I no longer experienced the behavior. This could have been a result of the debugger perhaps. I couldn't reproduce again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    s = r.Address
    s = s & vbCrLf & r.Address(1, 1)
    s = s & vbCrLf & r.Address(1, 0)
    s = s & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 1)
    s = s & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

You should see no colons.

Comment: Thanks @Gary's Student. Although I was unable to reproduce the behavior and couldn't test your code against my problem, I appreciate the answer and will use it when I experience the problem again!